# Define a table dynamically without using malloc in C

Tags: c, malloc

I want to define a table where the size depends on an input information.

The limitation is that I must not use dynamic allocation functions such as `malloc`.

***Input information:***

- Linked List
- Each item of this linked list has one field: `length`:

```
struct node {
    unsigned int length;
    struct node *next;
};
```

***How to calculate the size of table:***

- It should be equal to the number of items if only the `length` value of each item is less than 255,
- If the `length` is greater than 255, then the size should be:

```
(Nbr of Items where size < 255)+  (Nbr Item where size >= 255).
```

- (Nbr Item where size >= 255) is:

```
Sum for each item( 0x00U == (Len % 255) ? (Len / 255) :(Len / 255)+1) 
Note that it's an integer division
```

Example:

- List of 4 items:

> ```
>   Length field of  Item1 =245, 
>   Length field of  Item2 =165, 
>   Length field of  Item3 =101, 
>   Length field of  Item4 =16,
> ```

So the table size is 4

- List of 4 items:

> ```
>   Length field of  Item1 =500, 
>   Length field of  Item2 =510, 
>   Length field of  Item3 =1000, 
>   Length field of  Item4 =16,
> ```

So the table size is ((500/255)+1) + (510/255) +((1000/255)+1)+ (1) = 9

The problem is when I define a table with variable size:

```
unsigned int MyTable[size];
```

It generates an error. Because it needs a fixed size.

How to define this table without using dynamic allocation (`malloc`)?

Comment: Your VLA would be on the stack. MSVC (which does not support VLAs) allows you to allocate stack memory with [`_alloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-170) which is non-standard.

Comment: You need to write your own allocator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you are right it was a typo error. I'll update my post thank you.

Comment: You could use a caller-allocated linked list where the caller takes responsibility for the allocation of nodes. Or optionally passes along a function pointer to the allocator function. What this table thing has to do with the linked list, I don't understand however.